# Does each role have its own separate decay timer?

Tags: league-of-legends

With the advent of Season 9 in League of Legends, Riot has implemented separate ranks per role. If I am Platinum to Diamond in all of my roles, will I get a separate inactivity decay timer for each of them?

Comment: Hard to find an answer to this. Even [their faq page](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/204010760-Ranked-Play-FAQ#h3q1) doesn't help much. I would assume they arent all split as that would require significantly more games played

Comment: @VanBuzzKill I would expect this to become common knowledge in 2 weeks or so, when decay timers start for Diamond players who finished their placements on the first day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been confirmed that each role has its own separate decay timer.

However, when you play a position, the timer is reset for that position and every position with a lower rank. Decay timer also now only applies to Diamond 4 and above.

Decay timer remains the same as last season for Master+.

Source: https://nexus.leagueoflegends.com/en-us/2019/02/ask-riot-ranked-and-more-ranked/